# What is the ideal disk allocation size using our Nimble SAN?

Tags: san

I have seen many recommendations to use 64K disk allocation size for data drives such as from the SQL Server Setup Checklist on BrentOzar.com.

The best practice guide for using our Nimble SAN with SQL Server at http://www.scribd.com/doc/275409689/Nimble-Storage-SQL-Server states to use 8K allocation because SQL Server uses 8K pages.

I know SQL Server uses 8K pages, but I thought it actually worked with extents which are 8 x 8k pages = 64K. The Nimble SAN only supports up to 32K allocation and not 64K.

Should we use 32K for data and log files to align with the SAN when creating the drives in Windows, or use their recommendation of 8K?

Comment: If you have the ability to test it, I'd test it with various allocation unit sizes to understand the best performance you'll get with *your* setup.  You may want to test it using the [SQLIO performance testing kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20163).

Comment: While it is true that pages are 8k, SQL server sets out data an extent at a time so when writing it will always talk first to a 64k block. Then it will deal within 8k blocks. Probably best to keep to the 64k but again, nothing is better than testing in your own environment.

Comment: Thank you, Max and Josh! I will test it in our environment with SQLIO.